# Why can I access Core Data fetched entities right after fetching them but not when I'm in a different scope?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data

so here's the problem I had today. In one method of mine on a project I've been working on I fetch entities using core data, and it seems to work. Here's my method:

```
func getVehicles() {
    let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext
    let vehicleFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "VehicleEntity")

    do {
        allVehicles = try moc.executeFetchRequest(vehicleFetch) as! [VehicleEntity]

    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch vehicles: \(error)")
    }

}
```

I call that in my viewDidLoad method right after calling super.viewDidLoad.

I'm loading a property of those entities into a tableview and I do so like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("vehicleCell")

    cell!.textLabel!.text = allVehicles[indexPath.item].vehicleType!

    return cell!
}
```

That works great, and it returns the .vehicleType property from all the entities and and puts it in the table. Here's where my problem occurs, in the method that gets called when a row is selected:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedVehicle = allVehicles[indexPath.item]
    if let del = delegate {
        del.updateCurrentVehicle(selectedVehicle)
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Selected vehicle comes back with a bunch of weird data. Interacting with it in the console at a breakpoint has the .vehicleType property coming back as nil and it gives me an exception when I try to access other properties, all of which are of type NSNumber. If I go and fetch the data again like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedVehicle: VehicleEntity
    let moc = DataController().managedObjectContext
    let vehicleFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "VehicleEntity")

    do {
        selectedVehicle = try moc.executeFetchRequest(vehicleFetch)[indexPath.item] as! VehicleEntity
        //            allVehicles = fetchedVehicles

    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch vehicles: \(error)")
    }
    if let del = delegate {
        del.updateCurrentVehicle(selectedVehicle)
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Why am I not able to access the properties of entities in that array in my first way of selecting the row, but I am by reselecting it? Is this some weird bug, or some nuance of Swift I was unaware of?

If anyone could help explain this, I'd really appreciate it. I'm glad I made it work, but I'd really like to understand why one way works and the other way doesnt.

Edit in response to the comments:
VehicleEntity is in fact a subclass of NSManagedObject. Here is the code for updateCurrentVehicle:

```
protocol SavedVehicleDelegate {
func updateCurrentVehicle(newVehicle: VehicleEntity)
```

}

and

```
func updateCurrentVehicle(newVehicle: VehicleEntity) {
    setVehicleData(newVehicle)
}
```

Although the selectedVehicle has bad data before it gets passed into that method. I set a breakpoint in both the cellForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath methods, and in the former the data is fine and correct, but in the second the properties of the vehicle object are as I've described above.

The updateCurrentVehicle method is what I use to pass the selected VehicleEntity object back to the parent view (this is in a navigation controller)

I use the indexPath.item only because the tableview isn't divided up into sections, so the item just returns the overall index in the tableview as a whole, or that's my understanding of it anyways.

Comment: Is `VehicleEntity` an NSManagedObject subclass?  Can you show the code for `updateCurrentVehicle`?

Comment: What does the method `updateCurrentVehicle` do?

Comment: Since you're using a table view, you should use `NSIndexPath`'s `row` and `section` properties. I'm not sure what value `item` will have here.

Comment: You should always use `indexPath.row` with a tableview, regardless of whether the table has sections (a table always has at least one section anyway) although `item` will work, it isn't a good habit to get in to.

Comment: Is `DataController` a singleton?  You are creating a new instance of it in `getVehicles` which probably means you are creating a new `NSMangedObjectContext` instance.  I suspect that this is going out of scope and causing your problems.  Implement `DataController` as a singleton and use the shared instance or at least instantiate one instance for your entire app and pass that reference between view controllers

Comment: @Paulw11 Using multiple data controllers is working fine for me. The issue I had was from when I tried to use objects in the allVehicles array a second time. My workaround was using the second DataContext to fetch the objects a second time

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying.  If you only have a single DataController you can avoid the need to fetch the objects a second time.  There are times when you want to use multiple managed object contexts, but this doesn't seem to be one of them.

Comment: When I only fetched the objects a single time it was not working correctly though. I would fetch the objects, and then they would be accessed in the cellForRoeAtIndexPath method and it would be fine. But then when I selected a row and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath was called the entities in that array had weird data like nil for some properties and when certain properties were accessed it would throw an exception. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: I think @Paulw11 is correct - if it's not a singleton, the data controller and the associated context exist only in the scope where they are instantiated (getVehicles).  It's only good fortune that your cellForRowAtIndexPath works.  Post the code for the DataController class.